# Uncaught typeError: not a function for a private method in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I am trying to access a private method in my `MyAccount` class but it is giving an error of `uncaught typeError: this.displayTabOnClick not a function`. I can clearly confirm that it is a private method available in `MyAccount` class, the other similar method `displayTabOnPageLoad` works perfectly.

Below is the code snippet:

***MyAccount.ts file***

```
class MyAccount
{
  private displayTabOnClick(thisObj: JQuery, e:Event, callback?:()=>any): void {
    $(document).scrollTop(0);
    e.preventDefault()
    let hash = thisObj.prop('hash');

    // Update the location hash
    window.location.hash = hash;

    // Add Selected class to the current click elem
    // Remove selected class from other .menu-link elem
    thisObj.addClass('selected');
    $('.menu-link').not(thisObj).removeClass('selected');

    // Set Tab Header
    this.setHeader(hash);

    // Hide all sections
    // And display only the hashed section
    $('section').css('display','none');
    $(hash).css('display','block');
  }

  /**
  * Switch My Account Tab
  * According to the passed ID
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public switchTab (e?: Event): void {
      if (e && e.type === "click") {
          this.displayTabOnClick($('.menu-link'),e);
      }
      else {
          this.displayTabOnPageLoad($('.menu-link'));
      }
  }
}
```

***App.ts file***

```
// My Account Page
let page = new MyAccount;

if (URL.checkPath('/user/myaccount')) {
    page.switchTab();
}

$('.menu-link').click(page.switchTab);
```

Comment: Tried to compile this code. No errors if you exclude the missing methods. What are the differences between those two methods mentioned? The implementation does not seem to be important. Try to define a minimal example.

Comment: page.switchTab() is executing but the same function when passed to the click handler it gives typeerror

Answer (score 2):

You have `this` scoping issue when calling `$('.menu-link').click(page.switchTab);` (*this* is scoped to the caller, and not to the `page`)

One of the options to fix it:

```
$('.menu-link').click(e => page.switchTab(e));
```

Another one:

```
$('.menu-link').click(page.switchTab.bind(page));
```

I'd go with the first one as it keeps type safety.

Comment: Yeah.. How could I forget the lexical scope of `this` .. Mistake on my part .. Let me try out your code

Comment: btw i don't want to pass the `event` as arguments as I can get that object without passing in argument

Comment: did you pass `event` as parameter?

Comment: Look at the generated js files. The solution of @AlekseyL. is correct/

Comment: I bypassed using `private static function` and it was looking way more cleaner